# Manipulating button in a custom input file

Tags: javascript, jquery

When i use more than one input files, the remove button only works on first input. The intention is to be able to use several inputs without the action in one of them changing the rest. It seems that the code is not seeing the different IDs of the inputs. How do I make them see which input is undergoing changes, noting the ID of each?

```js
function bs_input_file() {
            $(".input-file").find('input').each(function (index, dom) {
                var id = dom.id;
                $("#" + id).parent().find("button.btn-reset").addClass("hidden");

                $(".input-file").before(
                    function () {
                        if (!$(this).prev().hasClass('input-ghost')) {
                            var element = $("<input type='file' id='" + id + "' class='input-ghost' style='visibility:hidden; height:0'>");
                            element.attr("name", $(this).attr("name"));
                            element.change(function () {
                                element.next(element).find('input').val((element.val()).split('\\').pop());
                            });
                            $(this).find("button.btn-choose").click(function () {
                                element.click();
                            });
                            $(this).find("button.btn-reset").click(function () {
                                element.val(null);
                                $(this).parents(".input-file").find('input').val('');
                                bs_input_file();
                            });
                            $(this).find('input').css("cursor", "pointer");
                            $(this).find('input').mousedown(function () {
                                $(this).parents('.input-file').prev().click();
                                return false;
                            });
                            console.log(element)
                            return element;
                        }
                    }
                );

                $("#" + id).change(function () {
                    var element = $("#" + id);
                    if (element.val() != "") {
                        $("#" + id).parent().find("button.btn-reset").removeClass("hidden");
                    } else {
                        $("#" + id).parent().find("button.btn-reset").addClass("hidden");
                    }

                })

            })
        }

        bs_input_file();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
  <h3>Example</h3>
    <form method="POST" action="#" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <!-- COMPONENT START -->
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="input-group input-file" name="Fichier1">
            <input id="fileInput0" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder='Select file...' />   
                <span class="input-group-btn">
                  <button class="btn btn-secondary btn-reset" type="button"><em class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></em></button>
                <button class="btn btn-default btn-choose " type="button"><em class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-open"></em> Search...</button>
            </span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="input-group input-file" name="Fichier2">
            <input id="fileInput1" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder='Select file...' />   
                <span class="input-group-btn">
                  <button class="btn btn-secondary btn-reset" type="button"><em class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></em></button>
                <button class="btn btn-default btn-choose " type="button"><em class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-open"></em> Search...</button>
            </span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- COMPONENT END -->
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont quite understand, but if you call a function via click event, you can pass in an event object. This has an attribute called target which has an attribute called id

```
function clicked(event){
console.log(event.target.id)
}
```